# Error MSB3094 when publishing AWS Lambda function

Tags: c#, aws-lambda

I am trying to publish an AWS Lambda function following this guide:
[Learning AWS Lambda : Creating a C# Lambda Function with .NET Core | packtpub.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zye3xpqLPWA&t=336s)

When I get to the 'Publish to AWS Lambda' step, I get the following error:

publish: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.2\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(137,5): error MSB3094: "DestinationFiles" refers to 1 item(s), and "SourceFiles" refers to 6 item(s). They must have the same number of items.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that moving the file to a different location fixed the issue. 
It was at C:\Users\my name\source\repos\project , but moving it to C:\project works. I am not sure why this was an issue.